# Moreinu Rosenheim's works

Tags: product-recommendation

Does anyone have a lead on where I could find Moreinu R' Jakob Rosenheim's *Samson Raphael Hirsch's Cultural Ideal and our Times* ? It appears to have been published in London in 1951, but the only concrete info I have found is its title and publication year on R' Rosenheim's German Wikipedia article.

Comment: The original in German is available online, if it helps. In English it appears to only be available in various libraries and a couple of used bookstores.

Comment: The English also seems to have originally been published in the Anglo-Jewish Association's The Jewish Monthly of 1951, but I haven't managed to find this online.

Comment: I can link you the German, if you're interested.

Comment: @Harel13, my German's not quite good enough ("miFrankfurt" refers to my yichus, rather than my place of birth)

Comment: Forgot to get back to you. I didn't think you were actually German. Sadly, I don't know German myself (I'm of Galician origins, but there are many torani books and essays on subjects that interest me, that are in German). If it's really important to me, I put in the effort to copy everything to Google Translate and hope the translation is roughly what the author had in mind. So if you're more looking for the basic idea of what he wrote - that's a possible avenue. For the exact text...well, there are secondhand editions available somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps slightly more helpful, https://portal.dnb.de/bookviewer/view/103281599X#page/15/mode/1up - the full book in German available online for free.

Comment: Hi. I'm going today to a university library to scan some hard to find books for personal use. They have a copy of this particular book/essay. Are you interested in a scanned copy?

Comment: @Harel13, yes !

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gq0aXgm4THYRocF7sUPa6oQPMSgO861Y/view?usp=sharing Enjoy! (Sorry some of the pages didn't come out so great (mostly in some of the corners), it was a little hard holding the pages open...)